# Orchard custom theme not being picked up

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a new Orchard 1.8 project and I created a new theme using

```
codegen theme Web
```

This created me a theme, I then logged into the Orchard admin panel and selected my new theme, I copied the Layout.cshtml from TheThemeMachine and when I try to access /Admin it has my site.CSS loaded which is all good and well, however I have a controller called Home with an Index view which is set to be the website index (Using ALIAS). When I navigate to the site address it displays my text but it doesn't seem to load my CSS file from the Layout.cshtml???

Does anyone know why my Layout.cshtml isn't being loaded? Or why it isn't loading my CSS file on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to decorate your controller with the attribute `[Themed]` and reference Orchard.Themes and add `using Orchard.Themes;`

Comment: That works perfectly Hazza cheers for that, I did have Themed before, but then I read I had to create a new Theme, so I then removed the Themed attribute and then created the new theme and I had my error :), I will accept the answer when it becomes possible